# Find out the default namespace URI from an XML document in C#

Tags: c#, xml

Some other questions have asked how to use Xpath to query XML documents with a default namespace. The answer is to use a namespace manager to create an alias for the default namespace, and use that alias in your xpaths.

However, what if you don't know the URI of the default namespace in advance? How do you find it out from the XML document?

Comment: Theoratically, you should know the namespace else you have no business parsing the XML file in the first place. Practically i know what you mean. What mechanism do you use to parse the XML?

Comment: I'm using System.Xml.XmlDocument

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(myXml);
XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using XmlDocument, you can get the default namespace by checking NamespaceURI of the root element:

```
var document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml("<root xmlns='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee'></root>");
var defaultNamespace = document.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI;
Assert.IsTrue(defaultNamespace == "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee");
```

Comment: I believe this is not correct. `document.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI` just returns the namespace of the root-element. This could very well be the namespace attached to some prefix instead of the default namespace. E.g. `<xsd:root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `XmlNamespaceManager.DefaultNamespace` to get it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.defaultnamespace.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but I had the same problem, using the XmlDocument class, as I wanted to know the Default Namespace and a prefixed namespace.

I could get both namespaces using the same Method.

```
string prefixns = element.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("prefix");
string defaultns = element.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("");
```

this seems to work for me getting both namespaces on a XmlElement.

Edit: This is a XmlNode Method, so should also work on Attributes

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(uriPath);
Console.WriteLine(xDoc.NamespaceURI);
```